# Reshape to wide based on standard monthly periods

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I am working with a large dataset in long format (after using melt) that I would now like to switch to a wide format before running a calculation on each row of the df

This long-form dataset ("dflong") has 7 columns: name, returnmonth, startmonth, descriptive1, descriptive2, descriptive3, and return.

I use the long format because I have multiple returnmonths for each name/startmonth pair. Specifically, I have the next 12 months of returns for each name and startmonth, and the startmonths span 10 years. This makes the df large: it has 1.2 million rows and those 7 columns.

What I would like next is to standardize the next 12 months for each name/startmonth and have a wide format where the right-most 12 columns are the returns in month startmonth+1, startmonth+2, etc regardless of what that actual month is. But I cannot just use the formula below because the returnmonths themselves differ, which I imagine would create a very, very wide df, which I do not want. (at this point, it's just giving me an error when I try to run it).

```
dfwide=reshape(dflong,idvar=c("name","startmonth","descriptive1","descriptive2","descriptive3"),timevar="returnmonth",direction="wide")
```

Is there a combination of reshape and some other tool that would allow me to both convert from long to wide but also not take into account the particular month that the return is coming from. This would form a long but manageable n rows*17 column dataframe to work with.

Appreciate your help very much.

Comment: provide reproducible example...otherwise, I assume you are familiar with melting using reshape2 package, get familiar with casting from the same package.

Answer (score 0):

This old question hasn't got an answer so far.

The OP has requested to reshape from long to wide format where the returns values should be arranged in 12 columns representing the 12 months after each startmonth.

This can be accomplished using the `dcast()` and `rowid()` functions from the `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(DT), name + startmonth + d1 + d2 + d3 ~ sprintf("M_%02i", rowid(name, startmonth)), 
      value.var = "return")
```

> ```
>        name startmonth d1 d2 d3  M_01   M_02   M_03   M_04   M_05   M_06   M_07   M_08   M_09   M_10   M_11  M_12
>     1: 0001 2000-01-01  A  B  C -56.0  -23.0  155.9    7.1   12.9  171.5   46.1 -126.5  -68.7  -44.6  122.4  36.0
>     2: 0001 2000-02-01  A  B  C  40.1   11.1  -55.6  178.7   49.8 -196.7   70.1  -47.3 -106.8  -21.8 -102.6 -72.9
>     3: 0001 2000-03-01  A  B  C -62.5 -168.7   83.8   15.3 -113.8  125.4   42.6  -29.5   89.5   87.8   82.2  68.9
>     4: 0001 2000-04-01  A  B  C  55.4   -6.2  -30.6  -38.0  -69.5  -20.8 -126.5  216.9  120.8 -112.3  -40.3 -46.7
>     5: 0001 2000-05-01  A  B  C  78.0   -8.3   25.3   -2.9   -4.3  136.9  -22.6  151.6 -154.9   58.5   12.4  21.6
>    ---                                                                                                           
> 95996: 0800 2009-08-01  A  B  C 136.5   79.6 -140.4 -216.5   35.3   31.4  -57.0   78.1  -53.3  -18.0   60.9 100.7
> 95997: 0800 2009-09-01  A  B  C  33.8  -12.5  -17.2   90.8  -24.7  -19.3  101.4  -39.1  139.4   15.5  -33.5  17.7
> 95998: 0800 2009-10-01  A  B  C  56.8 -121.2  242.4   -1.0   -9.9   78.2   34.6   31.8  -51.7  -11.1   45.0  89.1
> 95999: 0800 2009-11-01  A  B  C 158.8 -101.9 -271.8  -21.1  -24.6  108.0  185.3   82.3  -54.9  116.4  149.2 -30.4
> 96000: 0800 2009-12-01  A  B  C  34.9  -34.0  186.4   -3.7  -26.8   97.0    8.7   84.5  -35.5 -106.2 -165.0 188.0
> ```

#### Data

The OP hasn't provided a reproducible example, so we make up our own dummy data:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# 10 years of startmonths times 12 returnmonths times 800 names 
nn <- 800L
ns <- 10L * 12L
nr <- 12L
# cross join to create all combinations
DT <- CJ(name = sprintf("%04i", seq_len(nn)),
         startmonth = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), length.out = ns, by = "month"),
         returnmonth = seq_len(nr)
)
# compute returnmonth as sequence of 12 months after each startmonth 
DT[, returnmonth := startmonth + months(returnmonth)][]
# append other data columns
DT[, paste0("d", 1:3) := .("A", "B", "C")][]
set.seed(123L)
DT[, return := round(100 * rnorm(nrow(DT)), 1L)][]

str(DT)
```

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    1152000 obs. of  7 variables:
>  $ name       : chr  "0001" "0001" "0001" "0001" ...
>  $ startmonth : Date, format: "2000-01-01" "2000-01-01" "2000-01-01" "2000-01-01" ...
>  $ returnmonth: Date, format: "2000-02-01" "2000-03-01" "2000-04-01" "2000-05-01" ...
>  $ d1         : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
>  $ d2         : chr  "B" "B" "B" "B" ...
>  $ d3         : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
>  $ return     : num  -56 -23 155.9 7.1 12.9 ...
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
> ```